# ToggleSlide submenu

Tags: jquery

I want to create jquery sliding submenu. I'm trying to make it for 2 hours, but no effect. It isn't working

Here's the page where you can find the menu http://dev.craft-sector.eu/.
There are two submenus where are arrows.

Here's my JQ

```
<script>
$("nav li a")closest.(li.main_li).hover(
  function () {
    $(this).children("ul").stop(true,true).slideDown('slow');
  },
  function () {
    $(this).children("ul").stop(true,true).slideUp('slow');
  }
);
</script>
```

And here's menu

```
<nav>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Novinky</a></li>
    <li class="main_li"><a href="#">O portálu <span id="symbol">q</span></a>
        <ul class="submenu1">
            <li><a href="#">Jak se připojit</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Příkazy</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Pravidla</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Servery</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">CraftSector - team</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Kontakty</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Prodpořte nás</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Fórum</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">BanList</a></li>
    <li class="main_li"><a href="#">Návody <span id="symbol">q</span></a>
        <ul class="submenu1">
            <li><a href="#">Residence</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Fractions</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">PaintBall</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>                          
    <li><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">VIP</a></li>
</nav>
```

The clickable isn't `li` element but a element, so I can't select parent `li`.

I also want to to close it when you click elsewhere of menu also in different menu link.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using only CSS and HTML, which is a better solution than jquery as it doesn't require javascript at all.

Take a look at [this guide](http://line25.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-pure-css-dropdown-menu).